# Why do banana plugs need these holes?

Tags: connector, banana-jack

Why do banana plugs need these holes?

[image]

Comment: You can connect another banana plug in one of those holes.

Comment: They don't **need** it, it is a (nice and useful) **feature** of these particular plugs.

Comment: They are often called "stackable banana plugs"

Comment: @andre314 I think "stackable" specifically refers to the type with a jack that's collinear with the plug; at least that's how I use the term.

Comment: I much prefer the 'end stackable' to the 'side stackable' plug that you've illustrated. Once you have several stacked plugs going into the 19 mm (3/4") standard spacing of a meter input, the plug tips sticking through can short to each other, or to other things. With an end stackable plug, the plug tips stay insulated.

Comment: [Yo, dawg](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/xzibit-yo-dawg). They heard people liked banana plugs, so they put holes in your bana plugs so you can plug a banana plug while you plug a banana plug.

Comment: That choice of wire colours is making me twitch...

Comment: @BrianDrummond What's the matter with it? Standard Euro brown for hot, blue for neutral... *I'm not helping, am I...*

Comment: @BrianDrummond I have literally had that last week in my motorhome, fitting some USB/lighter sockets.  Opened up the cupboard panel on one side, checked the wires with a meter.  Brown hot, blue cold, fine.  Opened up the cupboard panel on the other side, brown and blue cables again.  Cut the cables.  Then thankfully I checked with a meter just before I wired them up, instead of making an assumption.  Brown cold, blue hot.  WTAF?!  The same guy wiring a van apparently couldn't even be consistent one day to the next.

Comment: It's called a bananana plug.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Right, but then why not "red for positive, black for ground" as well? Red on brown and black on blue would make perfect sense.

Comment: hence the "I'm not helping, am I" comment @TooTea

Comment: Brown phase wire to the black Neutral plug. | Blue Neutral wire to the Red (old code) phase plug.  | Go on throttle up! :-(

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Your banana plugs have holes so that the plugs can act as banana jacks.

You plug one banana plug into the plug panel of, say, a power supply.  You can then plug another banana plug into the first plug.

It's a helpful feature for making multiple connections with banana plugs.

Comment: "Jack" being "socket" in British English.

Answer (score 96):

Does this banana plug picture help you understand why: -

[image]

You can get different variants too: -

[image]

And end-stacking types: -

[image]

Comment: With 4 of them and a little skill you can (probably) get a mechanically almost locked 4 wire connection :-).

Comment: @RussellMcMahon it is not that difficult actually, it is not actually locked as it might seem. You just make two couples and then mate those.

Comment: @VladimirCravero Yes - I visualised how to put it together. Past experience (not with banana plugs) suggetss it MAY require "wriggling it all together" . Not hard but sometimes 3 hands needed. I'll try it some time :-)

Comment: If you have banana banana cables long enough, you can build yourself a nice pendant.

Comment: Banana #1 is also known as an insulated banana. The barely visible plastic around the pin helps against accidental short-circuits, particularly useful when working with mains voltage. This particular one probably has a retractable sheet, there are also plugs with fixed sheets. Those are less-stackable but even more safe.

Comment: I prefer the last position being banana #2

Comment: Nicely explained in picture :)